# How to generate a random binary number of a given length in Java given a limit on the maximum non-zero values?

Tags: java, binary

I want generate a series of random binary numbers in Java, with a specified limit on the maximum number of `1`'s it can have.

For example, if the threshold is 4 and binary numbers are to be of length 9, possible values are:

- `111100000`
- `100011010`
- `001111000`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: is this an assignment ?

Comment: I have tried using java.util.Random class. But I could only get to setting the range of values and not the number of 1s it could have. A crude way to do this could be just checking for the number of 1s and regenerating values the satisfied criteria is met..but that would be very time-consuming

Comment: Actually I need it to implement a feature selection algorithm that I have been working on.

Comment: Why do you think your proposed solution would be very time-consuming? Did you try it?

Comment: @Atul Never provide more information in comments; always try to edit your question and put "more text" there. Not everybody will (want to) read through all those comments ...

Comment: You could implement shuffle for a `long` or `BitSet` How do you want the distribution of the number of bit to be?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested algorithm:

1. Take a random number `n` between zero and `threshold` which will be the number of ones in the string (both ends inclusive)
2. Create an ArrayList `list` and add `n` ones to it.
3. Then add 9 minus `n` zeros to the same list
4. Call `Collections.shuffle(list)` to randomly shuffle the elements of the list
5. Convert the list to a String using a `StringBuilder`